# Inserting Data in Pivot Table

Tags: laravel

The two tables **tbl_product_manager** and  **tbl_tags**  with many to many relations. I used eloquent to to make a relations between the corresponding models. I am able to to insert the data in these two table but the problem is the pivot table is not updated correspondingly. 


**Controller.php:**

```
public function addProduct()
    {
        $rules = array('product_name' => 'required',
                       'product_url' => 'required');
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
        if($validator->fails()){
            Session::flash('class', 'alert alert-error');
            Session::flash('message', 'Some fields are missing');
            return View::make('admin.product.add');
        } 
        else {
            $productName = Input::get('product_name');
            $productUrl = Input::get('product_url');
            $productUrl = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $productUrl);
            $productExist = ProductManagementModel::checkExist($productUrl);
            if( count($productExist)!=0) {
                $message = 'product <b>'.$productName.'</b> with url <b>'.$productUrl.'</b> is already exist';
                Session::flash('class', 'alert alert-error');
                Session::flash('message', $message);    
                return View::make('admin.product.add');
            }
            else {
                $imageFile = Input::file('userfile');
                $destinationPath = 'uploads/products/';
                $rEFileTypes = "/^\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png){1}$/i";
                $maximum_filesize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

                if($imageFile) {
                    $filename = $imageFile->getClientOriginalName();
                    $extension = strrchr($filename, '.');
                    $size = $imageFile->getSize();                  
                    $new_image_name = "products" . "_" . time();

                    if ($size <= $maximum_filesize && preg_match($rEFileTypes, $extension)) {
                        $attachment = $imageFile->move($destinationPath, $new_image_name.$extension);                       
                    } else if (preg_match($rEFileTypes, $extension) == false) {
                        Session::flash('class', 'alert alert-error');
                        Session::flash('message', 'Warning : Invalid Image File!');
                        return View::make('admin.product_management.add');
                    } else if ($size > $maximum_filesize) {
                        Session::flash('class', 'alert alert-error');
                        Session::flash('message', "Warning : The size of the image shouldn't be more than 1MB!");
                        return View::make('admin.product_management.add');
                    }               
                }
                $logo = isset($attachment) ? $new_image_name . $extension : NULL;

                $objectProduct = new ProductManagementModel;
                $objectProduct->product_name        = Input::get('product_name');
                $objectProduct->product_url         = $productUrl;
                $objectProduct->category_id         = Input::get('category_id');
                $objectProduct->product_cost        = Input::get('product_cost');
                $objectProduct->product_short_description = Input::get('product_short_description');
                $objectProduct->product_description = Input::get('product_description');
                $objectProduct->is_active   = Input::get('is_active');
                $objectProduct->created_at  = Auth::user()->id;
                $objectProduct->updated_at  = Auth::user()->id; 

                if($logo != '')
                {
                $objectProduct->product_attachment = $logo; 
                }
                $objectTags = new TagModel;
                $objectTags->size_id = Input::get('size_id');
                $objectTags->brand_id = Input::get('brand_id');
                $objectTags->color_id = Input::get('color_id');
                $objectTags->food_id = Input::get('food_id');
                $objectTags->save();

                //$tag = new TagModel::all();

                $objectProduct->save();

                if(isset($request->tags)) {
                    $post->Tags()->sync($request->tags, false);
                }
                if($objectProduct->id) {
                    Session::flash('class', 'alert alert-success');
                    Session::flash('message', 'Product successfully added');
                    return View::make('admin.product_management.add');
                } else {
                    Session::flash('class', 'alert alert-error');
                    Session::flash('message', 'Something error');
                    return View::make('admin.product_management.add');
                }               
            }           
        }
    }
```

**ProductManagementModel.php**

```
 <?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class ProductManagementModel extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;
protected $table = 'product_manager';

public function Tags(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('TagModel', 'product_tag', 'product_id', 'tag_id');
}

public function Categories(){
    return $this->hasOne('CategoriesModel', 'id');
}

public static function getAllProducts(){
         return $products = ProductManagementModel::with('categories','tags')->get();
}

public static function checkExist($url)
{    
    return $products = DB::table('product_manager')
                ->where('is_deleted', 0)
                ->where('product_url', $url)
                ->first();              
}
```

}

TagModel.php

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class TagModel extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;
    protected $table = 'tag';
    public function ProductManagents() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('ProductManagentModel');
    }

    public function Color(){
        return $this->hasOne('ColorModel', 'color_id');
    }
    public  function Brand() {
        return $this->hasOne('BrandproModel','brand_id');
    }

    public  function size() {
        return $this->hasOne('SizeModel','size_id');
    }

    public function  food() {
        return $this->hasOne('FoodModel','food_id');
    }

}
```

During my research i found that using **sync** function will be appropriate to updated the pivot table. But I failed to use it. 
I am expecting to resolve this problem or something new way to find out the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look at attach, detach or synch method :
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Note it's more easily if you respect the eloquent naming convention
http://www.rappasoft.com/articles/laravel-eloquent-naming-convention-guide/

Comment: I am following the similar naming convention. Recently I followed your instruction from the link above. Still I am not able the updated pivot table.